# Unable to replace `$_` by something else in preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

I am investigating, but I am not able to find the solution to this.

The idea is to replace the characters `$_` from a string with something else.
If you remove the dollar sign from the `$search` variable, it kind of works (but not in a desirable way).

It is not working because the dollar sign is a special character, but I cannot find how to scape it.

This is what I have:

```php
$search = '$_'; // replace to '_' OR '[$_]' it returs "$1" instead of "1"
$replace = 1;
$regex = '#".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b' . $search . '\b#s';

$fullInput = '"$_" $_';

$r = preg_replace([$regex], $replace, $fullInput);

echo $r . PHP_EOL;

// Output with current code : "$_" $_
// Output with '_' or '[$_]': "$_" $1
//
// Expected result: "$_" 1
```

> To have into account, if the text is between quotes, it should not be replaced.

Comment: You should call `preg_quote` for `$search` term and remove `\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for search:

```sh
"[^\\"]*(?:\\.|[^\\"]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\$_
```

and replace it with `[$0]`

Pattern before `|` matches a double quoted string allowing an escaped quote in between. Pattern after `|` matches `$_`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PcbaGt/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `"[^\\"]*(?:\\.|[^\\"]*)*"`: Match a double quoted string. We allow escaped characters in this match.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)`: Skip and fail this match
- `|`: OR
- `\$_`: Match literal text `$_`

**Code:**

```sh
$search = '$_';
$replace = '[$0]';
$regex = '/"[^\\"]*(?:\\.|[^\\"]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '/';
$fullInput = '"$_" $_';
$r = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $fullInput);
echo $r . PHP_EOL;
```

**Output:**

```
"$_" [$_]
```